# Check whether a JSON / C# object meets SQL conditions

Tags: c#

I have a filtering criteria which is represented as a string of SQL conditions.

For example:

```
"(profile.country='United States' AND profile.gender!='Male') OR data.field="someValue"))"
```

Given a JSON:

```
{
    "profile"{
        "country": "England",
        "gender": "Female",
        "age": 30
    },
    "data" {
        "field": "someValue"
    }

}
```

I would like to check whether the given JSON (or alternatively a C# object) meets the conditions in the filtering criteria.
Is there some C# library that provides this functionality? (couldn't find one)
If not, then is there an optimal solution to achieve what I'm trying to do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry not sure what you're looking for. SQL code? C# code? Something to translate SQL into C#? Linq would be the most common way to query C# objects but it's a different syntax from SQL.

Comment: I am looking for a C# code which will get a JSON and a filtering criteria (represented as string of SQL conditions) as parameters, and return a Boolean value which will indicate whether the JSON meets the conditions in the filtering criteria.

Comment: Ok gotcha! I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box means or product to do that but hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: I'm assuming you have either tons of these filters already or they need to be dynamically creatable. (Otherwise why not just translate them to C# yourself, once). Poossibly crazy idea but depending on how much you need this to scale maybe it'd be worth it; you could save your C# objects (ie the deserialized JSON objects) to a SQLite database, then query them using SQL.